Could not work with the Nexus docker registry over public domain with a specified port(not 433)
I run a Nexus instant(OSS 3.69.0-02) by docker container on a local host. And create three docker related repos(docker-proxy, docker-host, docker-public). Repo docker-public contains docker-proxy and docker-host).
The following settings are made to enable anonymous access:

Enabled Anonymous Access -> Allow anonymous users to access the server
Added Realms -> Docker Bearer Token Realm
Enable docker-public's Allow anonymous docker pull.
Enable docker-public's HTTP connector with port 12188.

To make the repo available online, I add a proxy on Nginx Proxy Manager by add the record:
docker.xxxx.host:21222 -> http://192.168.1.12:12188.
Access by local ip
I can login the docker by the cmd docker login 192.168.1.12:12188 with the username and password.
login success by local ip
Access by domain
BUT, I cannot login it by using the domain:
login failed by domain
It seems strange why port 443 is used here. And ignored the port I specified 21222.
I dumped the tcp for the login process from the nexus server host .
It seems the request reached the nexus host at first, and responded a 401 Unauthorized and then the connection closed.
tcpdump: domain access from 192.168.1.21 where Nginx host
When I use a local ip, same think happened first. But it the following is different.
tcpdump: ip access from 192.168.1.23
Local IP can use the correct port for the seconds token request, but the domain request changed the port from 21222 to the 443(The nexus host could not receive the token request). Anyone know why and how to fix it ?

I paste the docker login log, but the quest could not published because it was identified as spam. lol...
